# Text will not wrap around image, need image to align to text top

Tags: html, css

I am pulling my thinning hair out. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I can't get all my text to flow to the left of the image. I have tried putting the figure outside and inside the surround divs, to no avail.

The abbreviated HTML:

```
        <div id="home_article_container" class="fluid">

            <div id="home_article" class="fluid">                            
                <h1>How It Works
                </h1>                                      
                <h2>Truck waste
                </h2>                            
                <figure class="images">                            
                     <img src="#" width="664" height="1000" alt="Overhead view" 
                     />                                      
                     <figcaption>The plant
                     </figcaption>                                
                </figure>                                                                              
                <p>Blah Blah Blah
                </p>                            
                <h2>Receiving building
                </h2>                            
                <p>
                Blah Blah Blah
                </p>                            
            </div> <!-- home_article-->                        

        </div> <!--home_article_container-->
```

CSS:

```
#home_article {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 55px 89px 55px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.images {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 2em 34px;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    float: right;
}

.images img {
    height: 21em;
    width: auto;
}

figcaption {
    font-family: "ff-meta-web-pro", sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    color: hsla(0,0%,18%,1.00);
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: .5em;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
```

Comment: Maybe #home_article{width: 100%;} will help you? I'm not sure if you want this?

Comment: Not really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6w7B/)

All you have to do is add this to the **CSS**:

```
h1,h2,p {
padding-left: 30px; }
```

And all your text is now neatly aligned with the images.
You can try other things too like percentages, margins...etc....

For more information on how to use padding in css: http://w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6w7B/ Or is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the paragraph and h2 text to move to the left and the image to the right. I also want the image to line up at top with the top of the paragrah text.

Comment: To align the image, you could do _img { padding-right: 30px; }_ and change the value to whatever you want, same goes for any other HTML element.